# How to get a mask from every country

Tags: image-processing

This is my map image

```
imgPro = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoj4F.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to get a mask from every country.But note the color is not very pure in my `imgPro`,which is a difficult points in this question.

```
Colorize[IntegerPart[
  ArrayComponents[Map[Total] /@ ImageData[imgPro]]]]
```

[image]

Note the part pointed by red arrow,which mean the color is slight different with the ambient color.This is a method by `DominantColors`.

```
Flatten[Image /@ Values[ComponentMeasurements[#, "Mask"]] & /@ 
  Rest[DominantColors[imgPro, Automatic, "CoverageImage", 
    MinColorDistance -> .1]]]
```

[image]

But I'm not very content with it,because I think it will fail to implement it when there are two adjacent country with similar color in the map image.Is there better method can do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example where it fails?

Comment: @rhermans I think that is a obvious result since the two or more similar color be recognized in one mask image [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0uAzF.png)

Comment: @rhermans Such as this image,`Uncompress[
 FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/4CaCz.png"], 
    "Byte"]]]]` or some case when the color is more similar.

Comment: How out if you find the smallest distance between any two colors in the image, and then set MinColorDistance in your call to DominantColors to a value less than this. Would this not insure that no colors get merged?

Comment: Another problem is with your source png file. Try `Tally[Flatten[ImageData[imgPro], 1]]` and you will see that there are "colors" that only occur in 1 or 2 pixels. You will have to trim them out, and this will involve a threshold.

Comment: Hello @bills, your [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146861/how-to-get-a-mask-from-every-country?noredirect=1#comment394686_146861) make sense,but note the `MinColorDistance` now always give a good result,considering the original `imgPro`,even I set a [very small values](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLnjR.png),the similar will appear in one mask image